# Add column to table with Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm new to back-end development and currently trying to add a column to my app_user table. like below.

```
- changeSet:
      id: 300520202335
      author: Malindu De Alwis
      changes:
        - addColumn:
            tableName: app_user
              columns:
              -column:
                name: address
                type: VARCHAR(255)
```

It gives this error

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
```

in 'reader', line 23, column 22:
                  columns:
                         ^

I use Spring boot and postgre sql. Please try to figureout the issue

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I found there were 2 things wrong with the example code given on liquibase.com:

- "columns" should be at the same indent as "tableName"
- The whitespace between "-" and "column" mentioned by others

The example should be

```
changeSet:
  id: addColumn-example
  author: liquibase-docs
  changes:
    - addColumn:
        tableName: person
        columns:
            - column:
                name: middlename
                type: varchar(50)
```

Somewhat disappointing that the official examples don't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an example yaml test changelog like the one included here : https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/testCasesChangeLog.yaml -- you will be able to replicate an `addColumn` change type in yaml format that works. For example:

```
    - changeSet:
        id: using after column attribute
        author: cmouttet
        changes:
            - addColumn:
                columns:
                    - column:
                        afterColumn: firstname
                        name: middlename
                        type: varchar(50)
                tableName: person
```

I believe @tobhai is correct though -- there is missing whitespace in `- column`.

Comment: can we add another -column with afterColumn:middlename

Answer (score 0):

I think the error results from missing whitespace between `-column`. Have you tried it with `- column`?